# how to get Category description to the bottom of the page magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, category, php

How can you move the categories description to the bottom .
all the answers on the web say go to `theme/category/view.phtml` 
search description ......

copy that and replace it at the botto and voilla .

But that DON'T work,so is there somebody who can tell the method that does work

Comment: can you please give a screen shot of page.. Thus easy to understand where are you want to use this

Comment: Try enable temple hints, to make sure you are editing the correct file

Comment: how do i add a print screen over here? @AmitBera

Comment: @R.S i ve tried to enable hints but exactly that block there is no path to see.

Comment: @AmitBera and here is the page i am takling about it is the same with every category page http://haak-sjop.nl/haak/spelden-knopen/knopen.html

Comment: @R.S here is the page i am takling about it is the same with every category page haak-sjop.nl/haak/spelden-knopen/knopen.html

Answer (score 0):

If copy category/view.phtml to your current store theme folder template location   folder That means

The template of `block type` ***catalog/category_view*** has been ***changed by any layout files***..

You need ***check all layout xml file*** at location ***app/design/frontend/YOUR_Package/Your_Template/layout***